# Call and exec function from class

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class and inside have a function where exec mysql query

```
$aUpdateAuLogs = DBC::$slave->selectAssoc("INSERT INTO auction_activity_logs (id_user, id_target) 
                                           VALUES ('{$aAuctionData['_key_']}'),('{$aAuctionData['watched_auctions']}')");
return $aUpdateAuLogs ;
```

so in my file i want to call and exec this after this foreach

```
foreach ($aExpAuction as $nAuctionID => $aAuctionData) 
{
    if (!array_key_exists($nAuctionID, $aWathedAuctions)) 
       continue;
}
```

Comment: And whats the question.?Is there any error or are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: i want to call and exec this function in my file after this foreach

Comment: There is no function, there is no class and 'my file' doesn't help either... You need to give much more info.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mrNYXnAm here is class
and here is my robot file http://pastebin.com/Ww7TMf4F

Comment: Don't pastebin your code. Include the relevant parts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to include your class where you want to use.
create class object.
call the function you want with created class object.

for instance,

i have a class called testClass

```
//tetsClass.php
<?php
    class testClass{
        public testFunction(){
            //function codes i simple return the string.
            return 'test output';
        }
    }

?>
```

after your forloop

```
        require(tetsClass.php);
    $testOBJ = new testClass();
    $var = $testOBJ->testFunction();
    echo $var;//it will print the text "test output"
```